# Using bold text formatting in php environment with flexbox

Tags: php, html, css, flexbox

I just recently started with coding , it's a small project and it's a web tool based on php and html. I started using flexbox to have more control over where snippets are on my site. I fetch a few things from my database and list them as shown in the example below. I have to use PHP because the actual content contains various php-parts to implement the data from the database.

```
//this is just an example, which when run, will show the problem...
//php part
echo "<div class='shell'>";
echo "<div class='shell a'>Headline<br> Something <br> another thing 
      <br> a third thing </div>";
echo "<div class='shell b'><b>Headline</b><br> Something <br> another thing 
      <br> a third thing </div>";
echo "<div class='shell c'><p><b>Headline</b><br> Something <br> another 
      thing <br> a third thing </p></div>";
echo "</div>";

//css part
.shell {display:flex; margin:auto; height:auto; width:600px; border: 1px 
solid black;justify-content:center;}
.a {width:auto;}
.b {width:auto;}
.c {width:auto;}
```

I want to use (shell b) for my boxes because without the (p) text formatting the box will only be around my actual text, example (shell c) will use space above and below the text, the border will show this. (Shell a) is there to show how it is supposed to look, and how i want (shell b) to look, with the bold headline.
The problem is, that if i format anything in any kind without wrapping it in (p) it will get its own "row" and the following text will not be listed directly below it. Is this a known problem and is there a solution to it?
I hope i could explain this so someone can understand it.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I added a picture so the problem can be seen without running the code somewhere.
[result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTUf1.png)

Comment: If you're just learning - I think you need to take a step or two back and look at the actual semantics of HTML.Then make it look nice... then maybe make it dynamic. It looks like you're trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: I alredy have a fully funktional tool, and I'm just trying to improve the look of it. I want to achieve that with flexbox, which resulted in the problem stated above. It really is just about making something bold without having to format it as a paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use `dispay: flex` on all `shell`, it will look like this

```css
.shell {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='shell'>
  <div class='shell a'>Headline<br> Something <br> another thing
    <br> a third thing </div>
  <div class='shell b'><b>Headline</b><br> Something <br> another thing
    <br> a third thing </div>
  <div class='shell c'>
    <p><b>Headline</b><br> Something <br> another thing <br> a third thing </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the reason, for the 2nd item, is the `<b></b>` tags, which will be treated as a flex item, and in combination with the text, which is an anonymous flex item, they will render side-by-side.

The 3rd item solves this by having a wrapper, the `p`.

---

If you only set `display: flex` on the outer `div`, it likely will look what you expect

```css
.shell.flex {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.shell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='shell flex'>
  <div class='shell a'>Headline<br> Something <br> another thing
    <br> a third thing </div>
  <div class='shell b'><b>Headline</b><br> Something <br> another thing
    <br> a third thing </div>
  <div class='shell c'>
    <p><b>Headline</b><br> Something <br> another thing <br> a third thing </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Note, I didn't used the `a`/`b`/`c` classes as `width: auto` is the default*

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for!